# Bash script command result inside other variable to define prompt

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to define a prompt which will indicate with colors whether the command executed properly and whether the command was found. As for now I have something like this but I does not work properly.

```
PS1="\`COMMAND_RESULT=\$\?;

if [ $COMMAND_RESULT -eq 127 ]; then echo \[\e[33m\] ---=== Command not found ===--- ;  

elif [ $COMMAND_RESULT -ne 0 ]; then echo \[\e[33m\]---=== \[\e[31m\]Oh noes, bad command \[\e[33m\]==---; 

fi\`

\n\[\e[0;37m\][\[\e[1;31m\]\@\[\e[0;37m\]] 

\[\e[0;32m\]\u\[\033[1;33m\]@\[\033[0;32m\]\h
```

As for now I get this error on bash start :

```
-bash: [: -eq: unary operator expected
-bash: [: -ne: unary operator expected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pollute your `PS1` with functions. You should use the special `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable to do this. The value of `PROMPT_COMMAND` is executed as a command prior to issuing each primary prompt.

Here is an example:

```
_check_command(){
   local COMMAND_RESULT=$?
   if [ $COMMAND_RESULT -eq 127 ]
   then
       echo -e "\e[1;33m---=== Command not found ===---\e[m"
   elif [ $COMMAND_RESULT -ne 0 ]
   then
       echo -e "\e[1;31m---=== Oh noes, bad command ===---\e[m"
   fi
}
PROMPT_COMMAND='_check_command'
PS1="\[\e[0;37m\][\[\e[1;31m\]\@\[\e[0;37m\]] \[\e[0;32m\]\u\[\033[1;33m\]@\[\033[0;32m\]\h "
```

There are many bash prompts you can find online to guide you. [Here](https://github.com/sharfah/dotfiles/blob/master/.bash/.bash_prompt) is one good example.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should not escape `$?` as `\$\?`. Looks like it gets interpreted literally.

Also you can check out the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt#.2Fetc.2Fbash.bashrc) article that shows how to implement something similar to what you want. Look at this line:

```
PS1="$(if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]]; then echo '\[\033[01;31m\]\h'; else echo '\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h'; fi)\[\033[01;34m\] \w \$([[ \$? != 0 ]] && echo \"\[\033[01;31m\]:(\[\033[01;34m\] \")\$\[\033[00m\] "
```

especially this part:

```
([[ \$? != 0 ]] && echo \"\[\033[01;31m\]:(\[\033[01;34m\] \")
```